# Applying DC voltage to a motor driver

Tags: motor, dc, inverter, motor-controller, motordriver

I have a 200VDC power supply from which I want to produce 110VAC 3 phase.

For this, I thought of using the most suitable motor drivers. I just wanted to ask you before I buy one.

As far as I know, the motor driver is already converting the AC voltage to DC with the bridge diodes in it. This made me think more about motor drivers.

All I want is to apply 200VDC and get 110VAC from its output.

I want to run a 1hp motor with this voltage.

- Can I apply 200VDC to the input of.a single-phase motor driver?
- Will this be a problem?
- What are your opinions?
- Do you know if motor drivers need any AC signals for microcontrollers, etc.?

Comment: It may or may not be possible, depending on how the motor driver has been designed. It may tell you in its data sheet. If you are asking about any conceivable motor driver, the question cannot be answered. If you are asking about the *use* of a particular motor driver, the question is off topic.

Comment: Bust usually DC motor drivers only entertain up to some 40VDC.  Do you have any particular driver in mind?

Comment: i have thought to use industrial drivers not low voltage circuits

Comment: I see. Just now I did a casual google search and found some drivers as high as 70V, but not higher than that. Do you have any link to 100V to 200V H-bridge drivers?

Comment: @tlfong01, the OP is asking about the possibility of using a commercial VFD with a 3-phase output to drive a 3-phase induction motor. OP wants to supply the internal DC link with 200 V DC.

Comment: My apologies to everybody, I am just a electronics hobbyist playing with DC motor drivers of toy motors.  I did not realize that this question is on industrial stuff.  Please ignore my earlier ignorant comments. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

As Charles said, a VFD can do this. But not all of them have an available jumper on the terminal block that is a connection between AC diode rectifier and DC bus. Therefore you should find those specific models, also you do need to provide adequate circuit breaker as from manual.

Now 200VDC link would be due to 140AC phase voltage, so your VFD has to be rated for a phase voltage greater than that, for example 200-240VAC @ 2HP/1.5kW or more. But before you make any action I would suggest you to take a photo of the motor nameplate and post it here.

Comment: thanks to assist. Motor is a compressor which  works with single phase voltage and it needs 60Hz of frequency. The compressor doesnt have any platename. Compressor is currently working on a device that supplied by single phase voltage and its 1hp for sure. So i think no need more spesific information , am i right ?

Comment: @qwertyqwq In a such case the VFD isn't a good choice. The VFD starts from 0Hz up to 60Hz, the single phase motor has a starting capacitor, which is determined for 60Hz. Also the inverter has to be rated for 1.5x more power (at least 2.2kW) if one phase is left unconnected. If you plan to use a VFD, then you should change the motor to 3ph, also.

Answer (score 2):

There are very few motor-drive inverters, more commonly known as variable frequency drives (VFDs), that are suitable for single-phase motors. Some types of single phase motors are not suitable for use with any VFD. Loads other than fans or centrifugal pumps are not necessarily suitable for use with such VFDs. Consumer conversion of single-phase AC motors to variable-speed is often problematic.

Most VFDs rectify the AC input and don't have any other connections to AC and thus, in principal, can work with DC input. However most manufactures provide specific guidance about DC input. It would not be a good idea to connect DC without consulting that guidance or to connect DC to a product for which no such guidance is given.